# (1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Tags: mysql, django, duplicates, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm getting this error `(1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'")`. This happened after I migrated my Django app from sqlite3 to MySQL. Here is the concerned table:

```
mysql> describe meddy1_specialization;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is the model:

```
class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the data in the table:

```
mysql> select * from meddy1_specialization;
+----+--------------------+
| id | name               |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Dentist            |
|  2 | Dermatologist      |
|  3 | Primary Care       |
|  4 | Ophthalmologist    |
|  5 | Pediatrician       |
|  6 | Orthopedist        |
|  7 | Ear, Nose & Throat |
|  8 | Gynecologist       |
|  9 | test               |
| 13 | test               |
| 14 | test1              |
+----+--------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If the error happened after you migrated the table, maybe you should say what you were actually doing *when* the error happened?

Comment: What is the `insert` or `update` statement that generates the error?

Comment: @GordonLinoff So I'm using Django and it hides the insert statements/takes care of it in the background. You can look at my model above which is from models.py. Also when I try to add data manually using MySQL insert statement from the console, it works. But when I try to add a specialization from the Django admin console, it gives me the error which is also the title of this post.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was trying to add a new specialization from the admin console.

Comment: Can you explain how did you migrate the database? Also, the version of django you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check in your mysql database what the incrementation number is at?
It seems that mysql is trying to insert a row with the same id.

Comment: Yes I checked that and told MySQL to increment from where the 'id' left off...14 in the example above. Didn't work. Then I deleted the 'id' column and re added. Didn't work. I used truncate to delete table with all data and recreate. Didn't work...

Comment: If you try to insert a row through MySQL self. Does that work or does that returns the error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the target_table is empty before you try the migration... delete all from the target table first. The error may be caused by duplication of an id number, even if it is = 0 (default for new record). Try to **explicitly define each of the id numbers** for each record.

In your case export from sqlite3 to a script.sql file, then find the data and add it to a script like;

```
insert into `meddy1_specialization` (`id`, `name`) VALUES 
(1 'Dentist'),
(2,'Dermatologist'),
(3,'Primary Care'),
(4,'Ophthalmologist'),
(5,'Pediatrician'),
...--plug in all your values in this fashion
```

Another scenario where this happens is when migration information from one Msql table to another... again explicit definitions might be required... one could add a column on the source table with the unique id and auto-increment this will then make migrating easier using that column...